# 301 (static page instead latest posts)

Tags: posts, pages, pagination, redirect, htaccess

I've changed the structure from the list of latest posts on the main page to static front page.
Latest posts were moved to "blog" page.

I need to redirect (301) old pagination structure from
**example.com/page/2/**
to a new one
**example.com/blog/page/2/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1. Plugin: [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/installation/)

This plugin allows you to manage 301 redirections. I played around with the settings and they allows regular expressions which could do the following:

- `http://some.site/page/2/` to `http://some.site/blog/page/2/`
- `http://some.site/page/3/` to `http://some.site/blog/page/3/`
- etc.

They provide documentation on how to set it up which can be found [here](http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/redirection/). This is what I've done when creating the rule, try this:

[image]

- **Source URL**: `/page/(\d*)/`
- **Target URL**: `/blog/page/(\d*)/`

I was testing this out on a local copy of WordPress and I don't have anything right now that gives me those URL structures. Let me know if that works for you on your end.

#### 2. Using `.htaccess`

If you don't want to use a plugin to manage your redirects, add the following to your `.htaccess`, in between the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/page/(.+?)(-[0-9]+)?$ /blog/page/$1
```

This is what your `.htaccess` should look like if you or a plugin haven't modified it:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# Redirect pages to blog
RedirectMatch 301 ^/page/(.+?)(-[0-9]+)?$ /blog/page/$1
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: I used the second method, simple and convenient. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help! Be sure to upvote the answer.